# Grading in Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

I am puzzled over something I read in Quillen's *[On the Cohomology and K-Theory of the General Linear Groups Over a Finite Field](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970825)*.

On page 557, when computing the $E_2$ page of a case of the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence, he first shows that

$$E_2 \cong \text{Tor}^{A_1}(k,k) \otimes k \otimes k \otimes A_4$$

In this formula,

- $\otimes = \otimes_k$
- $A_1 = k[x_1, x_2, \dots]$ with $x_i$ in degree $2i$
- $A_4 = k[y_1, y_2, \dots]$ with $y_i$ in degree $2i$.
- The isomorphism is an isomorphism of algebras.

Based on the isomorphism above he claims that 
$$E_2 \cong P[y_1, y_2, \dots] \otimes \Lambda_k[e_1, e_2, \dots]$$

where

- $\Lambda_R$ means "exterior algebra over $R$"
- $y_i \in E_2^{0,2i}$
- $e_i \in E_2^{-1,2i-1}$.

***Question:*** I am confused about the last point, that $e_i \in E_2^{-1,2i-1}$. My understanding of the "bigrading" on $\text{Tor}^{A_1}(k,k)$ is that I can take a graded projective resolution $P^{\bullet} \rightarrow k$, and then the second index comes from the fact that the (co)homology objects of $P^{\bullet} \otimes_{A_1} k$  inherit a grading.

Of course, I'm going to use the Koszul resolution. But then,

1. Shouldn't the generators $e_i$ live in degree $2i$ just like the $x_i$'s they're mapped to under $\Lambda_{A_1}[e_i] \rightarrow A_1$?
2. If so, doesn't that imply that $e_i \in E_2^{-1,2i}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different people use different notation on gradings,  for example I would have called the bigrdading of $e_i$ $E_2^{1,2i}$.  Supposing that this is not a typo, Quillen meant
by $k$ in  $E_s^{j,k}$ the total degree, not the internal degree of the element.
In other words, he has a spectral sequence $E_2^{s,t}\Rightarrow E_{\infty }^{t}$.

So you are right in 1, but in 2, the above definition of indices gives the shift.